# Hibernate Query whit function count

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, count

I am studying Hibernate and in a exercise I must do this query

```
"SELECT count(id) as numero_utenti, imc 
FROM Utenti 
WHERE azienda = '" + id + "' GROUP BY imc"
```

the problem is that, I don't know as view the result and to save the result in a string.

Thanks.

This is the function

```
public String getStat(int id) {

    String stat = "";
    int count = 0;
    try {
        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT count(id) as numero_utenti, imc FROM Utenti WHERE azienda = '" + id + "' GROUP BY imc");

        // as I extract the values​​?


        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        throw he;
    } 

    return stat;
}
```

Comment: Pls ask question properly. It is not understandable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking how to execute query using hibernate session.
query = session.createQuery("semect * from temp");
and query instance 
Long.valueOf(query.fetchCountOfRows()).intValue();
It'll give you no. row count.

Comment: sorry but query not have fetchCountOfRows function

Answer (score 0):

If they are not unique, get the list.

```
List<String> imcs= null;
int count = 0;

Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT imc FROM Utenti WHERE azienda = '" + id + "' GROUP BY imc");
imcs = query.list();
count = imcs.size();
```

Comment: I want print the number of user grouped by IMC. My query returns n lines with the number of user that have IMC = X